# Fix *.wav to *.mp3 with ffmpeg in command line?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, cmd.exe, mp3, wav

Something happened when I converted Mp3 to Wav.

The music lost quality, how can I get back Mp3 Quality with ffmpeg or anytools using command line?

Comment: you really need to edit your question to at least include the command string you used with ffmpeg , when you experierienced the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand the question, but David's edit helped.

Did you lose the original `MP3` and now you only have the `Wav` file, and you want to get back the "quality" you had in the `MP3`?

Unlike `MP3`, `Wav` is a lossless format, so sound quality should not have been lost in decoding `MP3` to `Wav`. (Not sure why you'd want that anyway in many cases, as that will greatly increase the file size and not increase the quality.)
On the other hand information **will** be lost if you encode it back to `MP3` from `Wav`, but you can of course try it, and see how it works for you.

What about simply `ffmpeg -i file.wav -q:a 0 file.mp3`?